# C++: ios::app doesnt need ios::out in fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

i was testing with flags in file stream objects the other day

And i did this.

```
fstream binf("h.txt", ios::app);
binf << "hey";
```

With fstream since i didnt use `ios::out`, the output operation shouldnt have worked , but it does work

I noticed that the the output operation works with `ios::app` only but if i use any other flag without `ios::out` it doesnt work

Can anyone tell me why I was able to output to the file while using only `ios::app` without `ios::out`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `app` implies `out`.

The standard specifies that `app` and `out|app` have the same result, equivalent to C fopen in mode `"a"`.

Comment: Yes.  The final answer is: "Because the standard says so".  The table defining the open modes uses `binary`, `int`, `out`, `trunk` and `app`, but only `in`, `out` and `app` are defined when used alone.

Answer (score 2):

Well, appending implies writing, that's about the longest explanation I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is more compiler specific,but they are amazing to be noticed:-

---

> **VS 2010** `fstream` :- **ios_base::out flag is already set**

```
explicit basic_ofstream(const char *_Filename,
        ios_base::openmode _Mode = ios_base::out,
        int _Prot = (int)ios_base::_Openprot)
        : _Mybase(&_Filebuffer)
        {   
        if (_Filebuffer.open(_Filename, _Mode | ios_base::out, _Prot) == 0)
            _Myios::setstate(ios_base::failbit);
        }
```

---

> **GCC 4.5** `fstream`:-  **Again ios_base::out flag is already set**

```
explicit
      basic_ofstream(const char* __s,
             ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::out|ios_base::trunc)
      : __ostream_type(), _M_filebuf()
      {
    this->init(&_M_filebuf);
    this->open(__s, __mode);
      }

void
      open(const char* __s,
       ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc)
      {
    if (!_M_filebuf.open(__s, __mode | ios_base::out))
      this->setstate(ios_base::failbit);
    else
      this->clear();
      }
```

And even more interesting thing is, only in `ios_base::in` the last bit is a `1`.Which signifies `ios_base::in` is able to retain its identity even raised with flag `ios_base::out`.

Comment: That's `ofstream` adding `out`, like `ifstream` is adding `in`. Plain `fstream` does not.