# Program says dictionary doesn't exist when it does

Tags: c++, file-io, static-libraries, spell-checking

I'm writing a spell checker using my library libspellcheck. I have a function to add a word to the dictionary. However, it keeps throwing an exception saying that the dictionary doesn't exist, when it really does. You can find the spell checker code on pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/1rCFAxDz. The function to add a word in the libspellcheck library is below:

```
void add_word(char *dict, char *word)
{
    ofstream dictionary;
    dictionary.open(dict, ios::out | ios::app); 
    if (dictionary.is_open())
    {
            dictionary << word;
            dictionary << "\n";
            dictionary.close();
    }
    else
    {
        throw 1;
    }

}
```

The function to check the spelling of the words uses the same dictionary variable, and it works fine. I am quite stumped. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just for funs and giggles, put a `char buff[256]; cout << getcwd(buff) << endl;` at the top of this function and see if your process is running where you *think* it is.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you are using the correct path?
like:

> C:\\Folder\\folder\...

sometimes you have to use 2 \\ instant of 1 \

Comment: I'm on Linux. The path I'm using is: /usr/etc/english.dict. I verified it using cat /usr/etc/english.dict.

Comment: ok so when you open the terminal and type: cd /usr/etc/            
it jumps to the directory ?

Comment: oh and btw you dont need the ios::out,
look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217202/c-iosapp-doesnt-need-iosout-in-fstream"

Comment: Yes. I created the directory on my machine

Comment: the code you posted has no errors, if the path is also correct i have no idea what is wrong

Comment: I am so dumb. I don't have the correct permissions to write the dictionary file. I've fixed that now :)