# Does ios::app not also imply ios::out in C++?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I have seen another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217202/c-iosapp-doesnt-need-iosout-in-fstream) in which the answer read that:

> Using `app` implies `out`. The standard specifies that app and out|app
>   have the same result, equivalent to C fopen in mode "a".

But it does not seem to happen in my case. I have made a small code to test this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream f;
    char ch[10]={"Hello"};
    f.open("Hello.txt",ios::app);
    f<<ch;
    if(f.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Failed to write\n";
    }
    cout<<ch<<endl;
    f.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

This gave me the output:

```
Failed to write
Hello
```

Also, it did not write anything to the file `Hello.txt` Does this mean that `ios::app` does not imply `ios::out`? Or, am I making a mistake?

Also, I tried to add `ios::out`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream f;
    char ch[10]={"Hello"};
    f.open("Hello.txt",ios::app|ios::out);
    f<<ch;
    if(f.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Failed to write\n";
    }
    cout<<ch<<endl;
    f.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

In this attempt, the program does work and it writes to the file as well.

Although this was quite convincing for me that `ios::app` does not implement `ios::out`but still the response to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217202/c-iosapp-doesnt-need-iosout-in-fstream) has still kept me in doubt since it also makes sense that if we want to append then we certainly want to write to the file.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, the first version works as expected for me.

Comment: I do not understand? Why does it not work on my system. I'm using MinGW as my compiler.

Comment: Maybe something peculiar about the way fstreams are implemented in MingW? Maybe dig into the implementation a bit and see if you can track down the issue? Does `std::fopen` work as documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of using `std::ios_base::out` and `std::ios_base::app` with `std::filebuf::open()` (well, actually, `std::basic_filebuf<...>::open()` is specified in Table 132. The three lines relevant for this discussion are the first three ones which map the `std::ios_base::openmode` to a file open mode used with `fopen()` (which in turn defines the semantics). The lines define the following mapping:

1. `std::ios_base::out` -> `"w"`
2. `std::ios_base::app` -> `"a"`
3. `std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app` -> `"a"`

That is, whether `std::ios_base::out` is specified in addition to `std::ios_base::app` is immaterial. If the behavior differs depending on `std::ios_base::out` being present the implementation should be wrong.

Comment: Does that mean MinGW has the wrong implementation for this thing? Please could you explain in simpler words? Thanks!

Comment: What the standard says is that it doesn't matter whether `std::ios_base::out` is specified when `std::ios_base::app` is specified. If a standard library implementation exhibits different behavior it is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get it now. You had mentioned some table 132. Please could you tell me the link to that table?(Curiosity to know what it is)

Comment: Table 132 is part of the C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2014), document number N4141 on [www.open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/). Sadly, the document is not freely accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Test on Win7 + Explorer with the first old c++ syle code shows the writen output.
But the same execute runs under notepad++ with NppExec with folow script shows another result:

```
npp_save
set GWDIR=G:\MinGW471
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
$(GWDIR)\bin\g++ "$(FILE_NAME)" -o $(NAME_PART) -std=c++11 -march=native -O3
NPP_RUN $(NAME_PART)
```

If I remeber right, under old Windows Explorer the first code shows what we like.

This c++ variant shows the result we expect under Explorer and NppExec:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch[10]={"Hello"};
    ofstream f("Hello.txt",ios::app);
    f<<ch;
    if(f.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Failed to write\n";
    }
    cout<<ch<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Excuse my english.